# how to install ubuntu when ubuntu is installed

Tags: system-installation

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on an acer Aspire-E3-112. Now i want to install it again because nothing works at the moment but ... How to install Ubuntu or a nother linux by using this ubuntu?
And I am a newby to the comman line
I dont have a live USB and can't use cd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Here is what you need to do, it's simple and no need command line : 1) Create an Ubuntu [bootable USB drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_a_bootable_Ubuntu_USB_flash_drive_from_Ubuntu) or a [bootable DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Burning_from_Ubuntu). 2) Boot from your USB (or DVD) and follow the Ubuntu installation as usual. 3) At step **Installation Type** select **Delete and reinstall Ubuntu**.

Comment: I gave instractions like in your bootable USB drive instruction, but the window doesn't appear

Comment: Open your dash and search for **Startup Disk Creator**.

Comment: what do u mean by "as usual"?

Comment: I meant the same way you have installed Ubuntu 14.04 **;)**

Comment: But back then I used Win8 which is not existing anymore sorry and thanks

Comment: how do I give order to boot that?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the distribution that you want here

```
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
```

Then from your desktop press the superuser button (the windows button on your keyboard) and search for startup disk creator. Plug in a blank USB stick with at least 2G of free memory and launch the startup disk creator. Select the distribution that you downloaded. Make sure that your bios is set to boot from a usb drive (which you can access by pressing a certain key such as F2 or esc while the computer boots) and reboot the computer. If your BIOS successfully boots from the USB drive you will see an option to install ubuntu. Select that option and follow the prompts.

Comment: thanks, there is now a window titled Installing and it sais "Copying files... Thanks so far

Comment: how do I give order to reboot?

Comment: use the command "sudo reboot" from the command line, enter your password and press enter

Comment: Thanks but that is not working because first it seems like it is shuting down, then the screen becams dark and nothing hapens for... well, I dind't wait longer than 5 min. but I can tell by the little lite in the back that the notebook is not really shut down ... so it looks like it is rebooting but nothing hapens...

Comment: any idea left, what may help?

Comment: Try powering the system off using the power button on the pc, and turning it back on that way. If your BIOS and live USB are configured correctly you should be able to install ubuntu when it reboots and that fresh install should hopefully fix the rebooting issue.

Comment: it is not starting to reboot after I turned it on again :-(

Comment: Is your BIOS attempting to boot from the usb or the hard drive?

Comment: I think so, my bios sais under the menu "boot" usb cdrom or usb hdd or usb fdd

Comment: or how do I set to boot from the usb

Comment: That sounds like it's attempting to boot from the usb. If you plug the usb stuck into another computer can you see that it has memory taken up by the live OS?